# Fatal Exception: UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

My app gets crash after live and from Crashlytics log, I can see crash detail as below

> Fatal Exception: UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation
>   Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [UIAlertController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES

I have similar code as below

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

And I find this crash only happens in iOS 8.3 and 8.4. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your target's device orientation settings?

[image: target's device orientation settings]

Comment: Yes, I have selected all choices

Comment: So are specifying a specific view controller to only have landscape rotation? Or you want the entire app to be available in every orientation?

Comment: I specify one view controller is landscape and others are portrait

Answer (score 0):

In every view controller, both landscape-only and portrait-only, override these three functions:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Notice that shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: is deprecated in iOS 6 and didn't get called since iOS 6 or 7